# Database connection in Entity Framework using EntityConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to build up a web app using ASP.Net Web API. But I'm finding it very hard to connect to the database. At first I used the Entity framework connection string from web.config and it gave me error

```
Keyword not supported: 'metadata'
```

So I searched for a long time and tried to implement the EntityConnectionStringBuilder as suggested in several solutions. I have a Product model generated using ADO.Net data model. When I try to access the getallproducts I get this error with nothing in my datareader.

```
'Product' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 37.
```

Now here's what I tried

ProductRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        //public string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MediaSoftAppEntities"].ConnectionString;


        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            string serverName = ".";
            string databaseName = "MediaSoftApp";

            // Initialize the connection string builder for the
            // underlying provider.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            //Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|
                        res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|
                        res://*/Models.Model1.msl";

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            string sql = String.Format("Select [pid], [pname], [price] FROM [Product]");

            using (EntityConnection con = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString())){
                using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand(sql, con)){
                    con.Open();
                    EntityDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(dr.Read()){
                        Product product = new Product();
                        product.pid = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        product.pname = dr.GetString(1);
                        product.price = dr.GetInt32(2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return products.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Product.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public int pid { get; set; }
        public string pname { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProductController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return repo.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Web.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MediaSoftAppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MediaSoftApp.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this should work without any problems if you use the right connection-settings - basically you have to copy the relevant parts from the projects app.config (where you created your EF-context/model) to your web.config - Please copy the first section of your web.config into your question

Comment: added the web.config code

Comment: Try to do what the error message is telling you to do, that is, qualify the reference to "Product" in the Entity SQL string. I don't see your .csdl file here, but I'm guessing something like `Select [pid], [pname], [price] FROM [MediaSoftAppEntities].[Products]` - note that you use the entity set name (which the tooling usually pluralizes, so Products, not Product) in the query.

Comment: now its saying `'pid' could not be resolved in the current scope or context`

Comment: Use `Select p.[pid], p.[pname], p.[price] FROM [MediaSoftAppEntities].[Products] AS p`. Entity SQL is a bit different than "normal" SQL.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me understand these silly things. It's working fine now after applying the way you specified.